# How to generate waveform for multiple audio files in Android?

Tags: android, ringdroid

I have used [Rindroid](https://github.com/google/ringdroid) to generate waveform for single audio file. Now I have to display the same audio track for more than one audio files which are selected from the device. How can I use this ringdroid to generate same waveform for multiple audios files.

Atleast is there any possiblity to maintain multiple player instances..?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please upload your code

Comment: code is there in https://github.com/google/ringdroid, We can create single player instance for one audio file from the github code, but How can I manage multiple player instances from the same code?